flutterflow List view refresh not working as expected - suggestion needed
so I created a page on which I basically have a list of food items organized per chefs.
These are 2 list view embedded. The first level is the Chef (yellow), and under a chef there are multiple food items (the blue frame)
In order to find the food item I have an Algolia search on a text field, when you hit enter it triggers the agolia search which return a JSON and then I use a custom action which has 4 parameters to filter the results
Parameter 1: the json with all menu items, Parameter 2,3 and 4 are cuisine type, diet type and allergyType (which respecitively help the user filter on their cuisine type they like or diet).
Currently it works when i search for a name item in the search textfield however these 3 parameter filters are drop downs. I would like the list view to basically refresh the list of items when I change the value of these filters however, i HAVE to go back to the search field (inputSearch) and hit enter for the whole process to run again and get the filter results.
I'm not sure on how to tackle this and have the list refresh even when i change the filters. (screenshot of my page attached) Any ideas? suggestions?
I tried to duplicate the action of the search field which generate the list of items displayed on individual drop downs but it doesn't do anything cuz the name of the output is different and i cant have the same output field name for 2 different actions.
